# Selenium Webdriver could not get some of the contents

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

https://www.forrent.com/apartment-community-profile/1012635

I am trying to parse a web page, such as this one. Selenium could return some of the content of this page, but not all of them. For example "***Professionally Managed by: B & A Associates***" is in the web page, but its not returned by the variable 'content' in the script. Any idea why is that, how to solve this problem?

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/home/yliu/repos/funnel_objects/listing_sites/geckodriver')                                                                                                     
try:                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(20)                                                                                                                                                                       
    driver.get(url)                                                                                                                                                                                         

    #WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "contactHeading")))                                                                                                             
    WebDriverWait(driver, 40)                                                                                                                                                                               
    html = driver.page_source                                                                                                                                                                               
    content = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")                                                                                                                                                                    
    driver.quit()                                                                                                                                                                                           
    return content                                                                                                                                                                                          
except TimeoutException:                                                                                                                                                                                    
    print('time out from contact')                                                                                                                                                                          
    return None
```

Comment: Have you tried other html parsers? `lxml` isn't always the best choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That content is a lazy load component. It will be displayed once you have scrolled down. So you need a script to scroll down to the bottom. See code below.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/home/yliu/repos/funnel_objects/listing_sites/geckodriver')                                                                                                     
try:                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(20)                                                                                                                                                                       
    driver.get(url)                                                                                                                                                                                         

    #WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "contactHeading")))                                                                                                             
    #WebDriverWait(driver, 40)
    SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5
    SCROLL_LENGTH = 200
    page_height = int(driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight"))
    scrollPosition = 0
    while scrollPosition < page_height:
        scrollPosition = scrollPosition + SCROLL_LENGTH
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, " + str(scrollPosition) + ");")
        time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    html = driver.page_source                                                                                                                                                                               
    content = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")                                                                                                                                                                    
    driver.quit()                                                                                                                                                                                           
    return content                                                                                                                                                                                          
except TimeoutException:                                                                                                                                                                                    
    print('time out from contact')                                                                                                                                                                          
    return None
```